# Gauss Bonnet for locally outermost closed minimal surface in Hawkings Theorem

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

So I'm trying to understand the proof for the following theorem from Lan-Hsuan Huang: "Trapped Surfaces, Topology of Black Holes, and the Positive
Mass Theorem":

Any orientable locally outermost closed
minimal surface $\Sigma$ in a Riemannian 3-manifold
$(M; g)$ with nonnegative scalar curvature must be a
topological sphere.

The proof starts with finding an outward normal variation $\Sigma_t$ with first order variation $X = e^u \nu$ and mean curvature $H_t$ such that $\partial_t H_t |_{t=0} = \lambda e^u$ for some constant $\lambda$. Further calculations lead then to the following inequality.

$\lambda \leq -\Delta_\Sigma u + K_\Sigma$

$\Delta_\Sigma$ denotes the Laplace-Beltrami Operator.

Integration yields:
$0 \leq \lambda * Area(\Sigma) \leq 2\pi \chi(\Sigma)$.

I know that $\int_\Sigma -\Delta_\Sigma u + K_\Sigma = 2\pi \chi(\Sigma)$ because of the Gauss Bonnet Theorem. But then I don't understand why $\int_\Sigma -\Delta_\Sigma u = \int_{\partial\Sigma} k_g$.

Comment: A closed surface, by definition, has empty boundary.